# Selenium Functional Testing Structure and Practices

Tags: javascript, selenium, functional-testing

A question for the testers out there:

Consider that you're writing a test like this: One opens a modal, flips a toggle to "on", saves its state (which closes the modal), then opens it again to check that the state was saved successfully. You also have to check that the toggle, when flipped back to "off", saves successfully and maintains the toggle's "off" state.

Is it reasonable to write your tests so that they chain off the previous test? It feels painfully inefficient to not chain them, especially if your starting process involves logging in, navigating to some page, clicking some tab, then getting started on the stuff you actually want to test.

Answer (score 1):

Although flipping to "on" and flipping to "off" are, *strictly speaking*, separately testable items, there's no need for you to test them in *complete isolation* - especially if it means that you have to reset data, re-do logins and navigation etc.

If you're confident that the two tests work together without one interfering with or polluting the other one, then just carry on with one single test.

Automated testers do need to be aware of the efficiency of their tests, and the amount of resources and time it takes to run the complete suite, because if they are too slow or expensive there will be pressure to cut-back.